# How to prevent flex-basis resize item image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Due to the `html markup` I had to use `flex-basis` to improve style, so that `p` element start from the same column as the `title/headline`, and problem was fixed using `flex-basis`. 
But as you can see in the screenshot, the image takes too much height and width.
I tried to fix it applying `max-height` and `max-width`, but it breaks my style.
And my goal is to remove that space so that i can control the space between the `content` and `button`.

**Note**: I can't use `css grid`. I know, it would be easier, but there are problems on ios using `css grid`.

[image]

Here is [the sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-dirac-3vwsnm?file=/style.css:0-693) and code snippet below

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: grey;
  column-gap: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo-image {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: top;
  padding-top: 10px;
  order: 1;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.headline {
  color: white;
  order: 2;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  order: 3;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <h4 class="headline">
          Block Title
        </h4>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm2og.png" width="50px" class="logo-image" alt="img" />
        <p class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente
          aliquid sit, cupiditate
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="btn">
        <button>link</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

][3](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-dirac-3vwsnm?file=/style.css) and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you make the image `position:absolute` so you wont need `flex-box`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: grey;
  column-gap: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 4rem;
}

.logo-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.headline {
  color: white;
  order: 2;
  margin:0 0 0.5rem;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin:0 0 10px;
  order: 3;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <h4 class="headline">
          Block Title
        </h4>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm2og.png" width="50px" class="logo-image" alt="img" />
        <p class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente
          aliquid sit, cupiditate
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="btn">
        <button>link</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, remove `flex-basis` on `.logo-image`.

Then put `h4.headline` and your `img` in its own `.wrapper` and add `display: flex;` to it. Then just set `img { max-width: 100%;)` so that your image resizes appropriately in the container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: grey;
  column-gap: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
}

.logo-image {
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: top;
  padding-top: 10px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.headline {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm2og.png" width="50px" class="logo-image" alt="img" />
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h4 class="headline">
          Block Title
        </h4>
        <div>
          <p class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente aliquid sit, cupiditate
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <button>link</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But as I mentioned, the problem is, that `p` element should start from the column as title. 
But here it start just under the image. But should be as in my screenshot only remove space occuring the image.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Greg no problem, see edits. You can now adjust the spacing from the image to the button by adjusting the `margin-bottom` on `h4.headline` and the `margin-top` on `p.text`.

Comment: @Greg  If you set those to `0` you will have removed the spacing.

Comment: unfortunately markup should stay the same, i can't touch the markup